# Messages not loading out onto ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to load some messages (which I get from an API call) onto a ListView. The messages are loaded and retrieved within an AsyncTask, but what i have posted is from the doInBackground() method down. Whenever I test the app, the ListView is empty...how can I fix this?

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
            String user = "User: " + array[x].getName();
            String subject = " Subject: " + array[x].getSubject();
            String body = " Body: " + array[x].getBody();

            String message = user + subject + body;

            aList.add(message);
        }


        //for (int i = 0; i < mess.length; ++i) {
              //aList.add(mess[i]);
            //}

        mess = aList.toArray(new String[aList.size()]);


        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean results){

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(ctx,mess);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;

      public Adapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.messages, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
      }
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, parent, false);

            return rowView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your getView() method, you aren't setting the values to anything. Assuming you have a textview defined in the R.layout.messages layout, then you need to retrieve it and set the text.

Something like this:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages, parent, false);
TextView txtView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
txtView.setText(values[position]);
```

Comment: I would add that rowView should be inflated only if convertView is null, otherwise convertView itself should be used. Also, it's a bad practice to change the adapter for a listView everytime the wrapped items are changing, so if that asyncTask is executed multiple times, consider using adapter.clear() and adapter.addAll(messages) instead.

Comment: I agree, you should instead use the ViewHolder pattern which is standard practice and it's easy to find several examples of its implementation.